Why is the SCF calculation performed after VC-RELAX more energetically stable than the VC-RELAX calculation in QE
Recently, I performed a vc-relax calculation in QE. After vc-relax, I performed an scf calculation, including all the optimized parameters from the vc-relax output file (cell parameters, atomic positions). Although the vc-relax calculation shows the ultimate optimized structure of a material, the subsequent scf calculation is more energetically stable than the vc-relax result. Can someone give me a comprehensive explanation?

+1, I too have seen this previously. However, in my case, the energy difference were in the order of $10^{-6};\mathrm{Ry}$ or less which I suspect might happen since they recalculate the G-vectors for scf calculation. That's why I didn't worry. How much is the energy difference in your case?

@AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine In one calculation I found  a 0.003821470000048066 difference, while another calculation showed no difference with VCR.

Most likely this is because your basis set is different before/after a variable-cell relaxation. The size of your basis set (i.e. number of planewaves) depends on the size of the unitcell: at fixed ecut, a bigger unitcell means more planewaves and better convergence.
Presumably the number of planewaves is calculated at the initial geometry and stays fixed during vc-relax so that, even as the unitcell changes size during relaxation, the basis set is constant. When you run the static SCF calculation after relaxation, you start with a different unitcell size than the relaxation and have a different basis set which affects convergence of e.g. total-energy.
You can try increasing ecut before relaxation and seeing if the difference in energy during relaxation and after is affected. I frequently use Abinit, which has options to handle this automatically.
Cheers!
Ty
